# unable to find an inherited method for function 'complete' for signature '"mids", "numeric"'

Tags: r

I just installed Rstudio and R with conda and I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/tutorial-powerful-packages-imputing-missing-values/

I run until this step

```
> completeData <- complete(imputed_Data,2)
```

I got the error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function 'complete' for signature '"mids",
>   "numeric"'

Does it has anything to do with how do i installed R? And do you know how to fix it? Thanks.

**More info**:

```
> R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)"
> packageVersion("mice")
[1] '2.46.0'
```

I tried traceback()

```
> traceback()
3: stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
       sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
2: (function (classes, fdef, mtable) 
   {
       methods <- .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable)
       if (length(methods) == 1L) 
           return(methods[[1L]])
       else if (length(methods) == 0L) {
           cnames <- paste0("\"", vapply(classes, as.character, 
               ""), "\"", collapse = ", ")
           stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
               sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
       }
       else stop("Internal error in finding inherited methods; didn't return a unique method", 
           domain = NA)
   })(list("mids", "numeric"), function (y, m, ...) 
   standardGeneric("complete"), <environment>)
1: complete(imputed_Data, 2)
```

And

```
> class(imputed_Data)
[1] "mids"
```

**For complete information:**

The code I run is :

```
library("mice")
library("Amelia")
library("Hmisc")
library("mi")
library("missForest")


data <- iris
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1)
imputed_Data <- mice(iris.mis, m=5, maxit = 50, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)
completeData <- complete(imputed_Data,2)
```

The complete output is:

```
> library("mice")
Loading required package: lattice
> library("Amelia")
Loading required package: Rcpp
## 
## Amelia II: Multiple Imputation
## (Version 1.7.4, built: 2015-12-05)
## Copyright (C) 2005-2018 James Honaker, Gary King and Matthew Blackwell
## Refer to http://gking.harvard.edu/amelia/ for more information
## 
> library("Hmisc")
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: Formula
Loading required package: ggplot2

Attaching package: 'Hmisc'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    format.pval, units

> library("mi")
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: stats4
mi (Version 1.0, packaged: 2015-04-16 14:03:10 UTC; goodrich)
mi  Copyright (C) 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 Trustees of Columbia University
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under the General Public License version 2 or later.
Execute RShowDoc('COPYING') for details.

Attaching package: 'mi'

The following objects are masked from 'package:mice':

    complete, pool

> library("missForest")
Loading required package: randomForest
randomForest 4.6-12
Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.

Attaching package: 'randomForest'

The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':

    margin

Loading required package: foreach
Loading required package: itertools
Loading required package: iterators
> 
> 
> data <- iris
> iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1)
> imputed_Data <- mice(iris.mis, m=5, maxit = 50, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)

 iter imp variable
  1   1  Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width  Species
 ...
  50   4  Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width  Species
  50   5  Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width  Species
> completeData <- complete(imputed_Data,2)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'complete' for signature '"mids", "numeric"'
>
```

Comment: I have loaded the library without issue, otherwise, I could not get imputed_Data. But that is how I got the same error.

Comment: what's the output of `R.Version()$version.string`, and of `packageVersion("mice")`?

Comment: > R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)"
> packageVersion("mice")
[1] '2.46.0'

Comment: It's possible you'll want to update R to 3.4.4. Clearly you've installed and loaded `mice`, and you're able to create the `"mids"` object, but it's having problems finding the method. The tutorial runs without a problem on R 3.4.4 with `mice` version 2.46.0.

Comment: Try it again, and then run `traceback()` (before you try updating to 3.4.4)

Comment: @DanHall,  thanks, I tried traceback() and got the error message as I updated the question. I will try to update R.

Comment: I don't think you need to update to 3.4.4. I'm only running 3.4.3 and I see a help page when I type: `?mice::complete`. Did you install and load pkg::mice?

Comment: @42 The issue isn't that `mice::complete` isn't available. It's running, and an error is thrown in a call inside that function.

Comment: The actual answer to your question is not in the linked question. Double check `class(imputed_Data)`. If it's both `"mids"` AND `"numeric"`, it wasn't generated correctly. It should only be `"mids"`.  This is an inaccurate error message, because `complete` does not have a method of class `"mids"`. You don't need one for it to run. `cbind` does, and I think that's where you're getting hung up.

Comment: @DanHall, it says the class is mids only...

Comment: @user40780: The question can be reopened if you [edit] your question to include full code to generate the error. Using links to webpages is deprecated on SO since pages may disappear or as is perhaps the case here packages may change and exhibit new infelicities.

Comment: I think this could be a useful and specific question, but @42 is correct, you need to post the actual code you ran (starting from a clean environment) for reproducibility, rather than just link to the tutorial. I would edit it myself, but the tutorial runs on my machine, so that wouldn't count as code that could reproduce an error.

Comment: @DanHall , Thanks, I added the completed code I run and the complete results. Hopefully this may be helpful...

Comment: I get the error. It's coming not from `mice::complete` but rather from `mi::complete`.

Comment: @42-, oh!!! this solves most confusion I have... To avoid such problem in the future. Could you hint me some method of checking/knowing which which function is from where?

Comment: I just typed the function name on the console and got this: `complete #
standardGeneric for "complete" defined from package "mi"`. Furthermore the possibility of having competing function definitions was raised by the fact that the help system on my machine brought up three possibilities when I typed `?complete`. (The third was in the tidyr package.) The other function name that I have similar experiences with such overlapping and contradictory behavior is with the function name: `describe`.

Comment: @42- , thank you so much! This solves all my confusions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at documentation that has a function whose name provokes that error, one needs to look "upstream" for packages that have been loaded. When use my browser's search function inside that page searching for `library` I see:

```
 #install package and load library
> install.packages("Amelia")
> library(Amelia)
```

And several other packages. You need to look at any package that was loaded before the code that you copied.

=== Edit ====

There are in essence competing methods for the `complete` function. Since the `mi` package was loaded last, it's `complete` function is being called but it's somewhat different than the `mice::complete` function and it fails to recognize an object of class mids that was created by the `mice`-function. If you force the proper function to be called, there is no error:

```
completeData <- mice::complete(imputed_Data,2)
str(completeData)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 5 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "contrasts")= num [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "2" "3"
```

Comment: I loaded all the required library previously already.... > library("mice")
> library("Amelia")
> library("missForest")
> library("mice")
> library("Hmisc")
> 
> completeData <- complete(imputed_Data,2)
 but it is not useful....

Comment: `complete` is not in `Amelia`. It's in `mice`.

Comment: So, @user40780 .... did you read _all_ of what I advised?

Comment: @42-, thanks for your info. I am trying hard to understand all of it. But since I just started using R, I am having a bit hard time....

Comment: You would have an easier time if you didn't jump to conclusions hastily and instead took a few deep breathes and read answers and comments slowly and carefully.

Comment: This is not a problem with loading the required package. `mice::complete` runs, and when it calls `.findInheritedMethods`an error is thrown.

Comment: @DanHall: So this is really a theoretically reproducible problem but is based on code that is outside SO. So it should still be closed but on a different basis than I had assumed. It can be reopened if the link to the tutorial is edited out and replaced with full code to generate the error.